# java.io.EOFException RecycleView

Tags: java, android, json, http, exception

I'm trying to parse a json file from an API and as argument in the request http I take the text field of a recycleview item

I make a toast to see if I recover the field text and indeed I recover it well

but when I run the http request I have an "java.io.EOFException" exception.

I tried to run the same request but instead of retrieving the text field I put the name directly in the request

but when I run the http request I have an "java.io.EOFException" exception.

I tried to run the same request but instead of retrieving the text field I put the name directly in the request

When I searched, I found that apparently the text field is null and that's why the query returns an exception but when I test with my toast it's wrong the field is not null!

that's how I get back the text field

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        String nom =  getItem(getAdapterPosition()) ;
        Toast.makeText(AppContext.getContext(),"string ; "+nom,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
```

so if for example in my request http i put like this

```
    http="........&nom=Canada........."
```

it's working

bt if i lanch my request like this

```
  String nom = getItem(getAdapterPosition()) ; // Canada
  http="..........&nom="+nom+"........"
```

it's not working

Answer (score 0):

post your RecycleView Adapter code and your onCreate() code !! so ican figure what you are missing !! it can be so many reasons !!!